# Синхронизация папки GoogleDrive

Tags: java, android, google-drive

GoogleDrive для ПК умеет синхронизировать определённую папку, можно ли это настроить как-то на Андроиде? Если да, то было бы отлично сделать это ещё из своего приложения?

Или если нет как вариант, где-то бы хорошую статью (желательно ру) как прикрутить гугл драйв к своему приложению так как с листания документации, у меня сложились некоторые сомнения...

Цель следующая: есть приложение, которое будет установлено на ограниченном количестве устройств, оно (скажем делает фотографии) и их нужно грузить куда-нибудь. Можно написать этот сервис самому, но возникает множество проблем, на подобие: проверка целостности данных, проверка что бы ВСЕ данные были загружены, как оно себя поведёт при плохом или потери соединения и т.д. Может у кого есть другие проверенные API или идеи, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Двухстороннюю синхронизацию с google drive можно настроить с помощью [Autosync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.drivesync). А вот со своего приложения посложнее. Можно взять любую api облака, но проблемы вы уже сами озвучили. Также можно рассмотреть [yandex disc sdk](https://yandex.ru/dev/disk/api/sdk/java-docpage/). Такой же есть у гугла, но он объявлен устаревшим и закроется в конце года.